# Problems with 2 arraylist

Tags: javascript

I currently have the following code:

```
articulo.prototype.crearEspecificAsoc = function ($table) {
    var lista = this.getColumnasEspec();
    //this.View.initTablaEspecificacion($table, this.lstEspecificacionesView, lista); 
    this.View.initTablaEspecificacion($table, this.lstEspecificacionesAsociadas, lista); 
    console.log(lista, ' lista');

    var lista2 = this.lstEspecificacionesAsociadas;

    var lista3 = lista2.sort();
    lista2[4] = lista.field;



    console.log(this.lstEspecificacionesAsociadas, 'this.lstEspecificacionesAsociadas');
    console.log(lista2, ' lista2');

    return true;
};

articulo.prototype.getColumnasEspec = function () {
    var arr = [];
    var objColumns = {};

    objColumns['field'] = 'IdNew';
    objColumns['title'] = 'Id';
    arr.push(objColumns);

    _.forEach(this.lstEspecificaciones, function (item, index) {

        objColumns = {};
        objColumns['field'] = item.Nombre;//'Valor';//Valor[i]/*.Valor*/;
        objColumns['title'] = item.Nombre;
        arr.push(objColumns);

        //objColumns = {};
        //objColumns['field'] = 'Valor';//NuevasColumnasAsoc[i].Valor;
        //objColumns['title'] = Espec_list.Nombre;
        //arr.push(objColumns);
    });

    return arr;
}
```

What I want to do is, that 2 arrays become 1. I explain it.[image]

I currently have the following code, what I want to do is, that 2 arrays become 1, I explain it.
Both in the second and the third, the same array1 is shown, what you want to do is place it in a single column, which says more or less what the first says, that columns are made that say the following: Id = 2, Nombre = Celestial Test, Peso = 85.

I appreciate the help.

**This is the answer I get now**

[image]

Comment: It will be easier to understand what you are asking if you provide an example of inputs and the expected output

Comment: I just edited the post, with the answer I get